# mysql innodb keeps crashing google cloud sql

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

My database (mysql) server (google cloud SQL) keeps crashing / restarting and I am at a loss of what to do.

```
Version: '5.5.46' socket: '' port: 0 (34, 36) (Google)
160427 7:20:12 [Note] : ready for connections.
160427 7:20:12 [Note] Event Scheduler: scheduler thread started with id 1
160427 7:20:12 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160427 7:20:11 InnoDB: 5.5.46 started; log sequence number 718527543
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
160427 7:20:06 InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
160427 7:20:06 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160427 7:20:06 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160427 7:20:06 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 96.0M
160427 7:20:06 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160427 7:20:06 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use InnoDB's own implementation
160427 7:20:06 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160427 7:20:06 [Note] (mysqld 5.5.46) starting as process 392594 ...
160427 7:20:06 [Warning] options --log-slow-admin-statements, --log-queries-not-using-indexes and --log-slow-slave-statements have no effect if
```

Comment: same problem here. seems like its increasing in frequency :(

Comment: Only possible reason left for us here is that the whole system is restarted for maintenance. But that shouldnt happen that often right?

Comment: We've had 3 unexplained reboots in the last week, which also seems more than necessary for maintenance.